# Is there a way in Visual Studio to save a "workspace profile", and swap between them, for documents opened within a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a very large solution that I work on for 95% of my work.  Much of my work is broken down into adding new features and maybe 25% of my work is spent in fixing bugs.

I also, some times, have to do a lot of research within the code.  This means that I might be working on a new feature (which could be weeks worth of work), I then have to research and fix a bug (could take days) and within the time frame that I am fixing the bug, someone might need me to research what's going on within some, specific task.

This means at any given time I might have 20-30 code files open for 3x different purposes, which happens more often than one might expect.

It would be nice if there was a way within VS a solution to save a "Profile", or something like that, that saves all of the open files and their layout since I often have multiple documents open side-by-side for reference in 2-3 panels.

If I create a profile for my projects, then profiles for each bug fix and, last, profiles for research request and just swap between them.

Is there a solution for this?  I assume there might be a plug-in in VS for something like this (which is a request more suited for Software Recommendations.SE) but my hope is that this is integrated into Visual Studio and I'm just missing the feature.

And just to be clear, I am using VS2019.  This is not VS Code.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn’t support what you describe

Comment: It's awkward even in VS Code, FTR.